# JOIN ON second highest value (Impala)

Tags: join, lag, impala, rank, lead

I don't know how or even if this is possible.... I am trying to JOIN tables on the second highest value. I tried rowNumber, lag, lead & rank  but haven't been able to get any of them to do what I need. To summarize, I'm just trying to shift the activitydate table down one row to join on rollDate minus 1 (but can't use -1 because they are not consistent dates, there are days missing.)

Does anyone know a good way to do this? Any suggestions are appreciated!

````
Select 
         ds.activitydate
        ,sum(ws.weeklyTotals / ds.daysBetween) as newRunRates -- getting an average of daily activity from weekly totals 
    from 
        (select 
             fsc.activitydate
            ,fsc.weekstart
            ,max(fsc.activitydate) OVER (partition by fsc.weekstart) as rollUpDate
            ,datediff(to_date(max(fsc.activitydate) OVER (partition by fsc.weekstart)), to_date(fsc.weekstart)) + 1 as daysBetween
        from fiscalcalendar fsc
        ) ds  -- used this to get a week-ending date bc that is what I need to join on. I only have a week start in this table 
    left join 
        (select 
             activitydate_iso 
            ,count(distinct assignedmaincomponentid) as weeklyTotals 
        from activityTable 
        group by 1
        ) ws  -- weeklySplits -- this gives me my weekly totals by a week ending date 
    on ds.rollUpDate = ws.activitydate_iso 
    -- need this join logic to actually be
    -- on ds.rollUpDate = (max(ws.activitydate_iso) where activitydate_iso < rollUpDate) 
    where activitydate between '2020-05-22' and '2020-06-15'
    group by 1,2
    order by 1,2 ```
````

Comment: Please show us the entire query (or a minimal working query that represents your use case), not just this partial code.

Comment: Thank you GMB. I've added the full query with some comments as well.